# Moralis Integration in Ionic Angular (typescript)

Tags: angular, typescript, metamask, moralis

I am creating an app in ionic angular (typescript). This app will run on both android and iOS devices.
I am integrating Moralis SDK so that I can connect to Metamask wallet.

Here’s what I did so far and I am stuck

1. created a new ionic project
2. installed moralis package via npm
3. initialized Moralis with application id and server url
4. authenticate using the following code:

```
   
this.user = await Moralis.authenticate({
        signingMessage: "Log in using Moralis",
      })
        .then(function (user) {
          console.log("logged in user:", user);
          console.log(user.get("ethAddress"));
        })
        .catch(function (error) {
          console.log(error);
        });
```

I am getting an error which says

> Error: Non ethereum enabled browser

I also tried running the project via ionic serve and it opens the Metamask extension when I click on the login button, and then authenticates the application.

I want the Metamask wallet application to open in my android device when I click on login button for authentication.

Can anyone help me out? Or tell me if there’s an existing boilerplate project for ionic?

Answer (score 0):

GM there!

For ionic mobile, you shouldn't expect that the Metamask button to work with Metamask mobile because the Metamask authentication is designed to work **ONLY** with Metamask browser extension on desktop browsers.

That is why the Metamask authentication is not working outside browser environment.

For mobile, Metamask mobile is accessible through WalletConnect (Metamask mobile is WC-compatible) or using the in-app browser in Metamask Mobile App.

Cheers~